# does "closely" mean "tightly"? does "place over" mean "place above each other"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

does "closely" mean "tightly"? does "place over" mean "place above each other"?

On this occasion Miss Cook's face was not visible, as her
head had to be **closely** bound up in a thick shawl, but I specially satisfied
myself that she was there. An attempt to throw the light direct on to her
uncovered face, when entranced, was attended with serious
consequences.

..When these two pictures are **placed over** each other, the
two photographs of myself coincide exactly as regards stature, etc., but
Katie is half a head taller than Miss Cook,...

https://books.google.com/books?id=ghqqNPvWHIQC&pg=PA284&lpg=PA284&dq=When+these+two+pictures+are+**placed+over**+each+other,+thetwo+photographs+of+myself+coincide+exactly+as+regards+stature,+etc.,+butKatie+is+half+a+head+taller+than+Miss+Cook&source=bl&ots=Bvk2xeS5s4&sig=ACfU3U0s0UHwP1YPd4mSeINLnT-69feLLQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjskYfbu__pAhUU9IUKHZZyAW4Q6AEwAHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=When%20these%20two%20pictures%20are%20**placed%20over**%20each%20other%2C%20thetwo%20photographs%20of%20myself%20coincide%20exactly%20as%20regards%20stature%2C%20etc.%2C%20butKatie%20is%20half%20a%20head%20taller%20than%20Miss%20Cook&f=false

Comment: Welcome to ELL :-). I would recommend separating these two in two questions as you are asking for meaning in context of two different expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the context of the text, closely means tightly but placed over means superimposed or overlayed.